# How to change structure of Master-Detail application for iOS in XCode?

Tags: ios, uitableview, master-detail

I am building an iOS application that is using the Master-Detail template.  What I need however, is to have an empty canvas on my initial screen, and have a detailViewController that does have a table view (i.e. switch the two views).

I am planning to place buttons on the main screen, one of which will in turn take me to the detailViewController that will have the table view.  I would prefer to do this programmatically vs storyboard because I have already started working on this project.

Comment: Why use the master-detail template if you want to change it, and do it in code?

Comment: The project changed after I started it, and so rather than creating a new template and copying the files over, I was wondering if there was a way to continue working with what I have, but change it to accommodate the new design.

Comment: Do you have what you want in the two controllers, and just want to switch which is the master and which the detail?

Comment: I included a bunch of code inside my viewDidLoad method of the MasterViewController, but I can always cut this out, and paste it into the detailViewController.  The detailViewController on the other hand is untouched.

Comment: I think you will have to move it -- you want master view controller to be a UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController, correct? It doesn't sound like you're that far into this project. You should just start over with the correct structure.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do I select your answer as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to move it -- you want master view controller to be a UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController, correct? It doesn't sound like you're that far into this project. You should just start over with the correct structure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct you want your master view to have some buttons with which you will navigate to the detail view. So, when you add the buttons and create each ones selector, then on the selector method use the method below. If I recall correct the Master-Detail template creates a navigation controller, so you have a navigation bar on top.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

To clear things out, when you press the button you call the selector of that button, which contains this method. Then you will navigating, by sliding to the right, to you detail view.